# Pandas: combine dataframes of different shapes based on comparisons between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dfs:

```
df1:
no1    no2    other1
1      10     foo
1      50     foo
1      60     cat
1      70     cat
3      12     cat

df2:
no1    start    stop    other2
1      2        40      dog
1      100      200     dog
3      5        15      dog
```

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` on the following conditions:

1) the no1 column matches, if that's true then

2) `df1['no2']` is between `df2['start']` and `df2['stop']`:

Desired output for the above example would be (don't need the `start/stop` columns, do need all other columns):

```
df3:
no1    no2    other1    other2
1      10     foo       dog
3      12     cat       dog
```

My tried solution (convoluted, probably not most efficient): I thought `np.where` might do it for me, using the code below and then dropping all rows where `df['merge'] = no`. But it's giving me a `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` error that I think has to do with the dfs being of different sizes. Efficiency/speed matters, so I think this isn't the way to go even if I could solve the error.

```
df2['merge'] = np.where((df1['no1'] == df2['no1'] & df2['start'] < df1['no2'] < df2['stop']), yes, no)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer-merge

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
```

then filter on rows

```
>>> merged[(merged.start <= merged.no2) & (merged.no2 <= merged.stop)][['no1', 'start', 'stop', 'other2']]
no1 start   stop    other2
0   1   2   40  dog
8   3   5   15  dog
```